# Mixing JQuery Mobile & JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

We're thinking to combine JQuery UI and Mobile. Does somebody has some experience with this ?

Past experience is proving  tricky [jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mixing-jquery-mobile-with-jquery-ui-widgets-don-t), but it's a bit old.

Any sharing of experience and ideas is welcomed.

Some experience using the JQuery Mobile virtual events ?

Thanks

Comment: to help get some meaningful answers, could you explain what you are looking to gain from the jquery UI framework that isn't in the jqm framework?  Thanks

Comment: It's the other way around, but : droppable, sortable, dialog,  resizable, autocomplete...

Comment: That would be pretty large in size for a mobile audience. I've used jQM before but not with jQuery UI on top of it.

Comment: it's not for mobile phones but for tablets

Answer (score 5):

The current version of jQuery UI 1.10.4 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 do not play well together. Styles in Mobile are ruined as soon as you include jQuery UI into your page.

However, if you need only particular functionality from jQuery UI, as in my case I only need Draggable/Droppable/Sortable interactions, you can create custom jQuery UI download at https://jqueryui.com/download/ and include interactions only. Then you can simply delete everything except js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js file and all works well together again.

I expect you'll run into issues using jQuery UI widgets even using this approach. But, it makes sense to use jQuery Mobile stuff only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting tablets and only tablets then this shouldn't be a problem. Just treat JQM as a Jquery plugin and JQuery UI as another plugin.

Its possible you'll run into some UI errors, but it can be fixed. We've worked on an Enterprise Application for one of our clients using *JQM and Jquery UI (for the datagrid and a few goodies) and High-charts*. The target platform was iPad.

EDIT: Its not an easy process, but you "can" make it work.

Comment: The target is tablets AND desktops, laptops

Comment: 3mio iPads sold in three days + iPad screen is big enough to not handle this as a mobile phone

Comment: If your layout is responsive... then I don't see any problem in implementing this. You just have to take care of what you use between Jquery UI components and Jquery Mobile UI components.

read this post for more information: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mixing-jquery-mobile-with-jquery-ui-widgets-don-t

Comment: Its old, but if you haven't seen it then here you go --> http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/27358432/Mobile