# jquery mobile1.4.2 and jquery-ui-1.8.18

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am working on `jquery-mobile` verison `1.4.2` with `jquery-ui 1.8.18`.

when I load the site, it's throwing an error  `a.widget.extend is not a function`.

If I replace jquery mobile file with `1.3.0`, then page is loading fine.

Do I need to upgrade UI version? If so what would be the version?

Comment: check which jQuery "core" you're using. Dont use less than 1.8.3, recommended is jQuery 1.9 with jQM 1.4.

Comment: Last time I checked, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile conflicted with each other when used together. See [Mixing JQuery Mobile & JQuery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9139316/464709).

Comment: are you loading jQuery Mobile before jQuery UI ?

Comment: Loading jQuery UI first and then JQuery Mobile